# chmod(): Operation not permitted in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gd

chmod(): Operation not permitted while uploading images in laravel at   localhost. Enabled GD library.
Testing environment is with ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10(WSL).

Comment: have you tried logging in as Admin ?

Comment: need more information

Comment: Look at the stack trace, the folder or file being chmod is probably owned by someone other than the webservers daemon user.

Answer (score 23):

I've just had the same problem. I've no idea why this happened, but in my case running `composer dumpautoload` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working with Laravel 8, Docker Desktop 4.2.0 (hosting Ubuntu-20.04) and WSL2 on Windows 10.

I experienced the same error after I successfully cleaned up my Laravel cached files within my Docker container with

```
sail artisan optimize:clear
```

On re-serving the application and reloading it on my browser, it reported some Filesystem error. The trace log pointed to a line where Laravel was trying to execute the `chmod()` command and returned with the error

> chmod(): Operation not permitted

I tried running

```
sail composer dumpautoload
```

within the my Docker container. The process ran for a while and then reported the same `chmod(): Operation not permitted` error on the command line.

This commands saved my day:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    composer dumpautoload
```

Simply copy and paste them to command line where you run your sail commands and hit enter. After the last composer command completes, you can now a access your application without `chmod()` flagging an error.

**WARNING**: Please backup your modified Laravel files; especially, `routes/web.php` before running the above command.

*UPDATE*

Got to the point of uploading files via a form and `chmod(): Operation not permitted` popped up again. The issue may be due to changes in the directory structure/information inadvertently caused by installing multiple dependencies via composer.

Also, Docker containers and Docker images for Laravel applications are managed by Laravel Sail. Sail sets user access policy to the application when you run `sail up`. It does this by creating new users for the docker images and associating them in groups *when the application starts*. You can confirm this by running:

```
sail artisan sail:publish
```

and checking the Docker files in the generated `docker` folder in your application root. They are actually used by Sail to spin up new containers for your app.

*SOLUTION*

If you have anything close to my setup and you encounter the `chmod(): Operation not permitted` error; simply stop Sail:

```
sail stop
```

Wait for all containers to stop running and then bring it back up:

```
sail up
```

Comment: sail stop && sail up works for me; It was because I start my container using Docker Destop instead of using "sail up" command.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the apache service user has access to your application folder.

Try:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/laravel-project
```

wherever **www-data** is user running the service apache2

Comment: This answer suffers from the same issues as chmod 0777.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while running Laravel on docker and sail. (using wsl on windows). For me, the problem was solved by adding this alias to my linux cli (can be opened by installing and running wsl command if you're using windows):

```
 alias sail='[ -f sail ] && sh sail || sh vendor/bin/sail'
```

And then after that whatever command you used to run just add sail before it.
like this:

```
sail composer install
```

or

```
sail php artisan migrate
```

Source: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#configuring-a-shell-alias)